# Perl using a sub call as argument to another sub - unexpected context

Tags: perl, compiler-errors

I am using a sub call as an argument to another sub. Example code:

```
test(isInString(), 'second parameter', 'third parameter');

sub test {
    my ($boolean, $second, $third) = @_;
    print "boolean: $boolean\n second: $second\n third: $third\n";
}

sub isInString {
    my $searchFor = 'a'; 
    my $searchIn = 'bcd';   

    return ($searchFor && $searchIn && ($searchIn =~ $searchFor));
}
```

In the example above, I would expect the return statement in "isInString" to evaluate to false ('' or undef or whatever that may be in perl), and this would be passed into "Test" as parameter #1, sou you'd essentially have

```
Test(undef, 'second parameter', 'third parameter');
```

That is not what happens though.  isInString returns an empty array, and essentially what you get is

```
Test('second parameter', 'third parameter');
```

returning from isInString in the perl debugger gives:

*list context return from main::isInString:
  empty array*

I'm assuming this is a perl context thing, I can assign to a scalar variable first and it works fine:

```
my $bool = isInString();
Test($bool, 'second parameter', 'third parameter');
```

debugger gives -
*scalar context return from main::isInString: ''*

***EDIT* I removed all parens with the same result:**

```
sub isInString {
        my $searchFor = 'a'; 
        my $searchIn = 'bcd';   

        return $searchFor && $searchIn && $searchIn =~ $searchFor;
    }
```

Debugger still gives:

*list context return from main::isInString:
  empty array*

Can someone please explain why it is returning a list context/empty array in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to force a "boolean context" you can use the double-negative "operator" : `!!`, like so:

```
test( !!isInString(), 'second parameter', 'third parameter' );
```

By calling it in a list of parameters, you've forced it into a "list context". You can force it back with something like this. One bang (`!`) evaluates it in a boolean context and makes it either 1 or `''`. But since you aren't testing for the complement, but the value itself, putting the other bang in there gets you back the value you wanted.

However, since it's pretty clear from the function body that you are returning a boolean value, and you're calling it in a list context (a *list* of parameters is a list context), you might want to force a *defined* value there. Like so:

```
return ($searchFor && $searchIn && $searchIn =~ $searchFor) || 0;
```

Any `undef` will result in a false value, and it will jump to the or and return the 0, which a list context will not ignore as it can an `undef`.

Comment: please see edit at the bottom of original post -removing parens yields same result, still a list context

Comment: @user210757, I fixed it, based on my own testing. Thanks.

Comment: this makes sense.  the or || method still returns list context though (0, 0), but it works.  is it bad practice to use a sub call inline like this, I do this all the time in other languages

Comment: @user210757, there's nothing wrong with nested function calls.  You just have to remember that they'll be called in list context unless you explicitly force scalar context.  (Or a prototype does.  But don't use prototypes.)

Comment: You could also do: `test( scalar isInString(), 'second parameter', 'third parameter' );`  Might be clearer than `!!`.  Might not.  YMMV.

Comment: If the function is supposed to return a boolean value the `return` should force it. It's bad API to expect the caller to.

Answer (score 7):

Your `return` is evaluated in list context because the function is called in list context. The boolean operators (like `&&`) do *not* force scalar context.

To quote [perlop on `&&`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-And):

> Scalar or list context propagates down
>   to the right operand if it is
>   evaluated.

Since the match operator returns an empty list on failure in list context, that's what you get.  If you want to force scalar context, use the `scalar` operator, either in your `return` statement, or when you call the function.

Also, the idea that parentheses force list context (as suggested by some of the other answers) is a common misconception.  They don't.  List context is the default; anything that *could* be list context is list context.  That's why there's no `list` operator that corresponds to `scalar`.  The one place where parens "force" list context is with the repetition operator.  `'a' x 3` means `'aaa'`, but `('a') x 3` means `('a', 'a', 'a')`.  But that's not actually forcing list context, it's just a special case for [the `x` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators).

Comment: $searchIn =~ $searchFor is going to return an empty array if the match fails, the parens don't matter in this case. scalar is the way to go.

Comment: The main reason that people think there's an association between parens and list context is that `@foo = (1, 2, 3)` does the obvious thing and `@foo = 1, 2, 3` doesn't -- but that's an *operator precedence* issue between assignment and comma.

Answer (score 0):

Not related to your question but `index()` is **more suitable** for your `isInString()` function.

```
index( $searchIn, $searchFor );
```

Comment: strange that index("abc", ""); returns 0 though, forces you to check for empty string first...